# Limiting specific schemas in BigQuery Datastream

Tags: google-bigquery, google-datastream

We want to use Datastream to extract data only from some customer databases contained in an RDS instance with multiple schemas, since the company does not allow sharing data from all of them as they are from different customers.

The documentation specifies that a MySQL user must be created who can be given permissions to specific schemas and tables.

However, the doubt arises to me, if Datastream is accessing to the binlog of the RSD instance, are not all the data of all the schemas being sent to Bigquery? Would we be sending data of all our clients?